# How to reference primary BC field in an Expression

Tags: siebel

I am writing a workflow in Siebel. I have a `Siebel Operation` box and I want to add some logic in the Input Argument tab. What I want is to compare a workflow input parameter (`Comment`) with a field of the main business component (`BCField`).

I have something like this:

**Field Input Arguments**

Field: Comment

Type: Expression

Value: `IIf([&Comment] IS NULL,[BCField], [&Comment])`

The logic here is if the workflow parameter Comment is `NULL` then set `Comment = BCField`. Otherwise, do nothing (or `Comment = Comment`).

If I try this I get an error: `Cannot parse expression.(SBL-BPR-00121)` because Siebel doesn't recognize `BCField`.

There is way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do it:

Put the BC you whose field you want to read in the Business Component Name fielnd in the Input Arguments tab.

**Field Input Arguments**

Field: Comment

Type: Expression

Value: `IIf([&Comment] IS NULL,[BCField], [&Comment])`

Business Component Name: `YourBC`